# Error while running xterm in telnet script

Tags: bash, shell, xterm

This is error while running the telnet script.
Language: Shell script

**Error:**

Type xterm -help for a full description.

```
xterm: Explicit shell already was /root/Desktop/stage2/./close_telnet.sh
xterm: bad command line option "192.168.0.1 25"

usage:  xterm [-/+132] [-C] [-Sccn] [-T string] [-/+ah] [-/+ai] [-/+aw]
    [-b number] [-/+bc] [-bcf milliseconds] [-bcn milliseconds] [-bd color]
    [-/+bdc] [-bg color] [-bw number] [-/+cb] [-cc classrange] [-/+cjk_width]
    [-class string] [-/+cm] [-/+cn] [-cr color] [-/+cu] [-/+dc]
    [-display displayname] [-e command args ...] [-fa pattern] [-fb fontname]
    [-/+fbb] [-/+fbx] [-fd pattern] [-fg color] [-fi fontname] [-fn fontname]
    [-fs size] [-/+fullscreen] [-fw fontname] [-fwb fontname] [-fx fontname]
    [%geom] [#geom] [-geometry geom] [-help] [-/+hm] [-/+hold] [-iconic]
    [-/+ie] [-/+im] [-into windowId] [-/+j] [-/+k8] [-kt keyboardtype] [-/+l]
    [-/+lc] [-lcc path] [-leftbar] [-lf filename] [-/+ls] [-/+maximized]
    [-/+mb] [-mc milliseconds] [-/+mesg] [-/+mk_width] [-ms color] [-n string]
    [-name string] [-nb number] [-/+nul] [-/+pc] [-/+pob] [-report-colors]
    [-report-fonts] [-rightbar] [-/+rv] [-/+rvc] [-/+rw] [-/+s] [-/+samename]
    [-/+sb] [-selbg color] [-selfg color] [-/+sf] [-sh number] [-/+si] [-/+sk]
    [-sl number] [-/+sm] [-/+sp] [-/+t] [-ti termid] [-title string]
    [-tm string] [-tn name] [-/+u8] [-/+uc] [-/+ulc] [-/+ulit] [-/+ut] [-/+vb]
    [-version] [-/+wc] [-/+wf] [-xrm resourcestring] [-ziconbeep percent]

Type xterm -help for a full desc
```

Please suggest any idea to solve this error.

Comment: Can you give the contents of parse.txt?

Comment: Seems like there is a line "Done!" in parse.txt and that gets somehow passed to xterm in `xterm -into $window_id -e ./close_telnet.sh "$line"`.

Comment: That "Done!" has no problem. I have removed that done from parse.txt file still it gives same error.

Answer (score 1):

The likely problem is that `$window_id` is an empty value.  That would produce the error message from xterm.

In a quick check, I have the output from `wmctrl -lp` as

```
$ wmctrl -lp                                                                    
0x00400023  0 1036         localhost.localdomain [!./bar] - vile           
0x00a0000a  0 3981   localhost.localdomain xclock xclock
```

but the output of the expression with `xprop` is **`0x0400023`** (a different number of leading zeros).

If I change the fragment

```
awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/,//' | sed 's/^0x/0x0/'
```

to

```
awk '{sub(",","",$5);printf("%#010x",$5);}'
```

it gives a usable result (for my machine: [***ymmv***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/YMMV)).